# Prevent outdated yarn.lock file from being committed?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

We switched to yarn recently for our project. One issue that has been popping up occasionally is outdated yarn.lock files. The package.json will have changes made to it and a dev forgets to `yarn install`.

Any ideas on how we can automate prevention of commits when we hit this situation?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that quickly is to use `yarn check --integrity`.
With `husky` you can ensure that by adding in your `package.json`:

```
"husky": {
  "hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "yarn check --integrity"
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Unfortunately, according to the yarn docs, `yarn check` has been historically buggy and undermaintained. It has thus been removed in Yarn 2. They recommend using `yarn install --check-files` instead, though it's unclear if it's a satisfactory substitute.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add a pre-commit hook that runs `yarn install`. This will update the lock file and shouldn't take too long as there won't likely be too many changes.

Install *husky* and *lint-staged* then add the following to your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "precommit": "lint-staged",
  ...
},
"lint-staged": {
  "*": [
    "yarn install",
    "git add"
  ]
},
```

I do something a little different for running *prettier* on .js/.json files but the basics are the same.